# InvalidOperationException: MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Trying to teach myself MVC. I am using database first in the MVC pattern.
I have scaffolded the controller and views. Yet when I run it I get this error?
I am not sure what to do since this was generated via automatically.

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'OPPS_APP11_7_2020.Models.ENT_PLANNERContext' while attempting to activate 'OPPS_APP11_7_2020.Controllers.ProductsController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is Database Context in the ProductController constructor, while it is not registered using Dependency inject (DI) in startup.cs in configureServices.
If you are not familiar with Dependency inject in ASP.Net core, I suggest you have a read about it, check [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

If you are using Entity framework (EF) there are special way to add their context in DI. check this [Configuring a DbContext in EF Core, Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

Answer (score 0):

After using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command to generate the relate models and the dbcontext based on your existing database, you have to register the DbContext to dependency injection in the Startup's ConfigureServices method.

Try to add the following code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //register the dbcontext.
        services.AddDbContext<ENT_PLANNERContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

You could add the connection string in the appsetting.json file:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "{your database connection string}"
  }
```

Reference:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx